# Which book of Dr. Rangacharya throws light upon Shankara Vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya

The following lines are from a book of Dr. Rangacharya:

> "That the aim of Shankaracharya was to try to evolve what he himself took to be the teachings of the Upanishads out of the Vedanta Sutras of Badrayana-that is, he put into the Sutras what he himself understood to be the teaching of the Upanishads."

Which book of Dr. Rangacharya throws light upon Shankara Vedanta specially mentioning his advaita as deviation from Bramha Sutras as quoted above?